# Render a new partial view on existing partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, gridview, devexpress

I am trying to do a drill down report. I am using MVC and Devexpress Gridviews. I render my view and the partial view and display my gridview with the result.

Now what I need to accomplished is when I double click on the gridview I need to render a new/different partial view in the place off the existing gridview - The one I double clicked on.

Is this possible?

**Here is what I have:**

```
    public ActionResult MainPartial()
    {  
        using (var Context = new DataContext())
        {
            ViewBag.Level = 0;
            return PartialView("MainPartial",SomeData);
        }
    }

    public ActionResult FirstDrilldownPartial(int Param)
    {  
        using (var Context = new DataContext())
        {
            ViewBag.Level = 1;
            return PartialView("FirstDrilldownPartial",SomeNewData(Param));
        }
    }
```

My Gridview RowDblClick event

```
function onDoubleClick(s, e) {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Controler/FirstDrilldownPartial',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        //cache: false,
        data: {
            Param: 1
        }
    });
}
```

At the moment everything is working but when I call the function **"function onDoubleClick(s, e)"** the Main grid stay on the view and the new grid is not rendered.

Can someone please help with suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: you kind of need a success event for your ajax call to do something with the return value of the FirstDrilldownPartial action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can render both partials in different divs and hide or show in your js function a div, for example

```
<div id="mydiv1">
    @Html.Partial("Partial1")
<div>
<div id="mydiv2">
    @Html.Partial("Partial2")
</div>
```

and in your onDoubleClick ( I assume that you are using jQuery)

```
$("#mydiv1").hide();
$("#mydiv2").show();
```

and to hide (on page load) the second div first just add

```
$(function () {
     $("#mydiv2").hide();
});
```

or use

```
<div id="mydiv2" style="display:none;">
```

This code is not tested, but it should work.